# VB.Net Winforms form ControlCollection is empty at runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I've been having a problem recreating a form from a dead project. The form is full of controls (132 of them, 38 of them are directly attached to the form, the rest are children of the 38).

When I try to run the application, I have code which focuses a textbox which is one of the base controls. However, debugging breaks at this point. The code was originally in the form's Load event, but I moved it to the forms Shown event to hopefully fix the problem.

It did not.

I did a little digging while the code was in break mode and discovered that the Controls property of the form was empty. Meaning that there were apparently no controls on the form.

This is weird because there is no controls added or removed until later. The controls property is untouched for a while, so it's not like everything is accidentally being removed. Any ideas?

Also I would copy some code in but I wouldn't know what to copy in.

As I mentioned above, everything works fine in the designer, so maybe the compiler is ripping it apart on compilation. I really don't know where to go on this one.

Thanks

Comment: Is the `$FORM.Designer.vb` present? Do you implement the constructor (namly: `Sub New()`) explicityl? Does it call `InitializeComponent()`?

Comment: (the form is called main)

Main.Designer.vb is there and functional, otherwise the designer view wouldn't work. I'm going to trawl through but I dont think I've explicitly implemented new().

Comment: Can you see any controls at design time?

Comment: For some reason New() was implemented with a few AddHandler statements (which are redundant because the controls the statements are adding handlers to are already handled.

Comment: Yes Matt designer worked fine. I've sorted it now, New() was implemented without InitializeComponent. Not something I've added mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem found & solved.

As MrPaulch said, a sneaky `New()` was implemented without the `InitializeComponent()` call needed to generate the controls.

For anybody else who has this problem, check for the `New()` which has probably been hidden which is ruining everything.

Comment: The IDE creates a working constructor when you open the method from the menus

Comment: The IDE can't be trusted to do anything properly. It struggles to reliably save changes made in the designer without throwing up errors saying if failed to commit changes. Intellisense also regularly shits the bed and reports errors where there are none.